# PHP/ MySQL: What is the best way to get filtered data from a database that has been inputted by a logged in user?

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I am trying to create a page that displays a preview of all the data that each individual user has put into the database.  Each user must only be able to see their own data.

I have been using $SESSION's to post which logged in user is inputting what, and have tried to get my brain to think about the reverse action.

I first wondered whether I could do

SELECT *
FROM `input`
WHERE `input`.bodyshop_name=$_SESSION ['MM_Username']

But that did not work.

As you can probably tell, I am new to PHP/MySQL, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `input` WHERE `input`.`bodyshop_name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['MM_Username'])."'";
```

Note the use of mysql_real_escape_string to sanatize any unwanted data.

Comment: Thank you.  Just one last question, what would the funtion be called please, I'm struggling a little?

Comment: I'm not sure what function you are after... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to call up all the records that relate to the logged in user.  I think the function will be read_input, but I am not quite sure as it's not going to input, it will call down those records.

Answer (score 1):

if bodyshop_name is the username of the user who input that data, then a query like you said should work.

make sure $_SESSION['MM_Username'] is in single quotes when you write the query.